# Gradle modifying files before war creation

Tags: java, gradle, war

I want to create a custom `war` task in gradle which has some complex functionality. I have succeeded in creating separate tasks that do each function but I can't seem to be able to combine them. Here are the steps I want to follow:

1. Minify a bunch of javascript files contained under a certain folder and add THOSE in the `war` and NOT the non-minified ones (obviously in the path the non-minified files were originally).
2. Take some `.java` files from a folder outside the project and add them to a specific path in the war for them to be compiled.
3. After all this is done produce the `war` but leave the source project INTACT (i.e. the changes above should only affect the produced `war` not the project structure itself because it will mess development).

I have successfully been able to minify a bunch of .js files from a folder and add them to a new folder but not include them in the war as a replacement for the original ones.
I have also successfully been able to take the required .java files and paste them into my source project before war creation but this messes up the project itself. I want this step to be executed only when producing a war.
Finally I have NOT been able to combine all of these into one chain dependent task. It seems that configuring the `war` task using the `war {}` doesn't work well with dependencies. The `war` task gets executed before the minification and the copy-paste task giving a bad result...